# unit testing angular component with input.require

Tags: angular, angular-test

When my components are like this

```
export OldComponent {
    @input required!: string;
}
```

I can prepare the unit tests like this:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OldComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
component.required = 'test';
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Now that we have input signals (Angular 17)

```
export NewComponent {
    required = input.required<string>();
}
```

How do we prepare the component for testing? This doesn't compille because an input signal is read-only:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NewComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
component.required.set('test'); // Does not compile
fixture.detectChanges();
```

I tried not assigning it for the tests, but obviously it throws:
`Error: NG0950: Input is required but no value is available yet. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0950`

I would not like to use the workaround of using a normal, not required input:
`input<string>('default value')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set inputs, you can use `ComponentRef<T>.setInput` method, which also works with signals:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NewComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
fixture.componentRef.setInput('required', 'test');
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Comment: Not working for me, I get the following error:
`NG0303: Can't set value of the 'example' input on the 'ExampleComponent' component. Make sure that the 'example' property is annotated with @Input() or a mapped @Input('example') exists.`.
Adding `@Input` decorator to the property in component results in:
`Using @Input with a signal input is not allowed.`

Comment: Well, error clearly states that the `example` is not an input, are you sure that you marked the property as the component input?

Comment: I have it declared as `input.required<string>();`, and as I mentioned if I add a `@Input()` decorator it results in an error `Using @Input with a signal input is not allowed.` and the app won't run

Comment: @Matej 1. You should not use input decorator and signal input at once. 
2. The problem lays in your code definitely, which is difficult to answer in the comments, without seeing the code. Post another question because your question is not related to OP's question.

Comment: @Matej are you using jest? My OP question was with the default test suite, but when I swapped to jest I got the same error you mention.

Comment: I am using the default test suite it installed when I created the project using Nx, which is using jest, so I guess that's the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you by any chance use the preview feature Zoneless it can be achieved like so:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PostComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
component.id = input('test');

await fixture.whenStable();
```